# How can I order an arrow2 Chunk by a given column in rust?

Tags: sorting, rust, apache-arrow, rust-arrow2

I have loaded a large arrow2 Chunk with a large set of columns/arrays and before writing it to a parquet file, I would like to order it by a given column. Look at this code:

```
fn main(){
    use arrow2::{array::*, compute::sort};
    use arrow2::chunk::Chunk;

    let mut col1: Int64Vec = Int64Vec::new();
    col1.push(Some(0));
    col1.push(Some(5));
    col1.push(Some(3));
    col1.push(Some(2));

    let mut col2: Int64Vec = Int64Vec::new();
    col2.push(Some(1));
    col2.push(Some(2));
    col2.push(Some(3));
    col2.push(Some(4));

    let mut chu = Chunk::new(vec![col1.into_arc(), col2.into_arc()]);

    chu.sort_by_key();

}
```

Obviously this fails, since it wouldn't know by which column to sort, but I have been unable to use any of the .sort_* functions. I would like to sort 'chu' by the first column.

I have tried to write the index extracting function for the '.sort_by_key' function, but no dice. Also google and geminied about it...

Comment: It looks like you want a dataframe library, e.g. [`polars`](https://docs.rs/polars).

Comment: Well, polars could certainly do it, but shouldn't arrow be able to perform this as well?

Comment: I did get it using polars, thought. It does pain me to add extra ~60 modules to the code for such a simple task. Maybe I will revisit this in the future. Thx for the insight @ChayimFriedman.